# How to update an object in the object context including its relationships

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, code-first

I update an object in the object context with data from the data source using this code:

```
 public class Project
    {
      public string Id{get;set;}
      public string Name{get;set;}
    }
 public class People
    { 
      public string Id{get;set;}
      public string Name{get;set;}
      public IList<Project> ProjectList{get;set;}
    }

 ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)Orm).ObjectContext.Refresh(
            System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, people);
```

It updates people but not ProjectList(navigation properties),so the question is:
How to update an object including its relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't do it automatically like that, Refresh only works on the primitive properties of a single object. If you need additional refreshes you need to loop through the objects and refresh each one.

Naturally a better approach would be to reload the entire graph with eager loading, if you don't really need to keep the objects since you're refreshing them.